# remove character like |n, |p, |q from regex

Tags: c#, regex

|p,|q from the string expression for example "what is |n ABC |p"?

it can be any character after '|'

i tried

```
"[\\|.]"
```

but with no success.

Comment: Inside a character class the characters `|` and `.` are interpreted literally. Why did you use a character class in the first place? `\|.` (`@"\|."` as a C# string literal) is obvious.

Comment: you could use this pattern: `(\|.+)+`

Comment: What Jon said. I'd quickly like to add that The Regex Coach, is a really useful tool for working with and testing Regular Expressions. Including describing in prose what your regex does.

Answer (score 0):

No need to put `|` and `.` inside a character class as the engine will treat them literally. So with your character class `[\\|.]`  your searching for one character out of `\`, `|` or `.` (literally).

What you want to do is to match on `|.` (read: the character `|` and one other character after it).

```
string strRegex = @"\|.";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"what is |n ABC |p";
string strReplace = @"";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Every found match is replaced with nothing.
(code taken from [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net))